# Database column naming for foreign key

Tags: database, naming-conventions

should I signal the foreign key in a database column name?

FKOrder vs. FK_Order vs. Order

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is no - don't put "FK" in column names of foreign key columns. You can still signal the intent of the column though, here's how I do it:

### Naming foreign key columns

It depends on your naming convention for the target of the FK. If you have `Id`, then I'd prepend the table name when creating FK columns.

**Example 1:**
For table `User` with PK `Id` and table `Workitem` with user ID FK, I'd call the column `Workitem.UserId`.

If there were more than one FK between the same tables, I'd make this clear in the column name:

**Example 2:**
For table `User` with PK `Id` and table `Workitem` with "assigned to user ID" and "created by user ID" FKs, I'd call the columns `Workitem.CreatedByUserId` and  `Workitem.AssignedToUserId`.

If your naming convention for PKs is more like `UserId`, then you'd factor that into the above examples so as not to end up with `UserUserId`.

### Naming foreign key constraints

This is mine:

```
FK_childtablename_[differentiator]parenttablename
```

The differentiator is used when there is more than one FK between the same two tables (e.g. `CreatedByUserId` and `AssignedToUserId`). Often I use the child table's column name for this.

**Example 1:**
Given tables: `Workitem` and `User`
Where `User` has `CreatedByUserId` and `AssignedToUserId`
Foreign key names are `FK_Workitem_User_CreatedByUser` and `FK_Workitem_AssignedToUser`

I use double-underscores if tables/columns have underscores in the name:

**Example 2:**
Given tables: `work_item` and `user`
Where `user` has `created_by_user_id` and `assigned_to_user_id`
Foreign key names are `FK_work_item__created_by_user` and `FK_work_item__assigned_to_user`

Comment: You have shown the FK _constraint_ name, not the column name :)

Answer (score 1):

Is usual to name the foreign key fields with an ID (IDORDER, IDPERSON, ...), if you have a table called PERSONS and another CITIES, if one person is in certain city, CITIES has an IDCITY field (K), PERSONS has a IDPERSON (K), and other field IDCITY (FK).

Hope this answers your question. I mean, a foreign key is only foreign when it's in other table, but not in theirs. But it's a good practice to name always the same to the same fields, even if they are in other tables, as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.

If a column becomes a foreign key later, you will have to change the column name, breaking all the scripts that are using it.

If there are multiple foreign keys, you don't know which column belongs to which key, so the only information you gain is that the column is a foreign key, but you already know it by looking at the keys.

Usually I name the foreign key column the same as the primary key, so I know immediately where the key maps.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the same name as the referenced column in the table holding the FK.

Only if this is potentially confusing (or a column with this name already exists, say `id`), would I be more explicit. In such a case, adding the entity type name before the rest - say `ProductId`.

Answer (score 0):

My style is slightly different:

```
fk_table_column
```

eg: `fk_user_id` that is foreign key to `User` table on `id` column. I do not use any capital latter.